# filter name and username from datagridview using textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010, vb.net-module

i am using combobox for option search name and username and textbox for filter
there are error

missing operator

[image: Error Image]

```vb
        Try
            If Trim(TextBox1.Text) <> "" Then

                dataadapter1 = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * form login where " & ComboBox2.Text & " like '%" & Trim$(TextBox1.Text) & "%'", conn)

                datasetaccounts.Clear()
                dataadapter1.Fill(datasetaccounts, "login")

                DataGridView1.DataSource = datasetaccounts
                DataGridView1.DataMember = "login"
                DataGridView1.Refresh()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error !: " + ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ...
```

rather than:

```sql
SELECT * FORM ...
```

So nothing to do with filtering or `ComboBoxes` or `DataGridViews` or any of that. It's exactly what the error message told you: a syntax error in your SQL code.